# Detecting a user-initiated column resize in SWT

Tags: java, swt

How can I tell when a column is resized by the user in an SWT `TreeViewer`?  I initially thought it would be via `ControlAdapter`, but this also fires on initialization and if the application window gets resized.

Is it more appropriate to add a drag or mouseup listener?  It doesn't seem (to me) that the `TreeColumn` initially supports this kind of behavior.

Comment: What do you want to do on the resize?

Comment: I would like to track when a user purposely resized a column. When new data comes in, the column widths get resized to fit that data. If the user purposely resized that column, the column would be left alone (aka not auto-resized).